# need help on creating a counter with a total, number enter, and average

Tags: c#

The requirement are:
create an application that will allow the user to enter numbers and
provide the average of the numbers entered.  The user will be allowed to enter as many numbers as they choose.  After each entry we will display the current average.
Keep repeating until the user decides to quit.

I want to user to keep entering number until they type "q" to quit. Please help.

```
string input = "";
        int numbersEntered = 0;
        int average = 0;
        int total = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number or Q to quit", input);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            total += Convert.ToInt32(input);
            average = (total / numbersEntered);

            Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}\t Numbers Entered: {1}\t Average: {2}\t", total, numbersEntered++, average);

        }

        while (input.ToUpper() == "Q");

        {
              Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();  

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: if these answers are helping you, then you should mark them as answers.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `Console.ReadLine` inside the loop -- and put the writing of the total/average *after* calculating those numbers.

Also, you might want to validate the input, instead of assuming it is a number -- use `int.TryParse`.

```
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of Q to quit", input);
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        int val;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out val))
        {
            total += val;
            average = (total / numbersEntered);
            Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}\t Numbers Entered: {1}\t Average: {2}\t", total, numbersEntered++, average);
        }
    }
    while (input.ToUpper() != "Q");
```

Comment: I want the user to keep entering number until they type "q" to quit.

Comment: @Snow. I guess you got confused with the do and while construct. They come together. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 1):

There are three points needs to be corrected.

1. numbersEntered is 0 in the first calculation. You should pre-increment it while dividing by it.
2. also in the condation of while loop, it should be input.ToUpper() != "Q" instead of input.ToUpper() == "Q".
3. After correcting above two things your current code is calculating the average but it clearing the console after printing it. So, you should want after printing it by Console.Read();

Following is the code corrected:

```
        string input = "";
        int numbersEntered = 0;
        int average = 0;
        int total = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number or Q to quit", input);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            int valueEntered;
            if (int.TryParse(input, out valueEntered))
            {
                total += valueEntered;
                average = (total / ++numbersEntered);
                Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}\t Numbers Entered: {1}\t Average: {2}\t", total, numbersEntered, average);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        while (input.ToUpper() != "Q");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: but when i type "q" int the program is doesn't display "press any key to continue".

Comment: It is showing "press any key to continue" on entering q. when you are enter any number it will show you the result and then wait to press any key, then after entry new number or q and press entry, it will show this message....

Answer (score 0):

Simply a typo(?) Your `while` needs to be:

```
...
while (input.ToUpper() != "Q");
```

That is `!=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic solution:

```
int nTotal = 0;
double avg = 0;
string input;

while ((input = Console.ReadLine()).ToUpper() != "Q")
{
    int number = int.Parse(input);
    avg += (number-avg) / ++nTotal;
    Console.WriteLine("Total numbers entered: {0}. Average: {1}", nTotal, avg);
}
```